# What are the possible ways that I can change the URL / redirect in client side code?

Tags: javascript, url, window.location

I am trying to understand all of the ways a user can programatically be directed to another site, for work with cross-domain tracking with google analytics.

As far as I understand it the only ways to change the page a user is on are through *window.location*, *history.back()*, *history.forward()*, *history.go()*.

Is there anyone with experience with this that can confirm if this is a comprehensive list or not?

Comment: That is not a comprehensive list, but asking for all possible ways is too broad. One possible way is to create a `meta` tag with `http-equiv="refresh"` and the `content` to the appropriate value; see [Meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

Comment: Thank's for this one, it looks like it won't affect me, but it is good to know. It really isn't too broad. I am trying to make a list of best practices for my organization, and without knowing the possible ways it is hard to make recommendations on what to do or not. I suppose we can't cover "all" possible ways, but I'm trying to understand the current state of the web APIs to be able to make an educated decision, but do not see any resources online to support this.

Comment: And perhaps Stack Overflow is not the right site to support that. See the [help/dont-ask], specifically "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”"

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on a better site to get help for programming questions, and working in a modern web environment, to curate knowledge, and build a developer community?

Comment: See [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/194720)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your observations. As far as I know, without the use of PHP and/or other languages (ie. only pure javascript/html), the `window.location` and `history` objects are the only way to redirect a user within a webpage.